# Specify how a container is replaced with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating my kubernetes cluster through deis.
Currently when ever rolling out new deploys, kubernetes will start new containers before terminating the old. However in certain cases, it's more desirable to kill the old container before starting the new container to avoid racing. How can I specify such behavior with kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Deis is no longer being actively maintained and it will see its  EOL January 2018.  We recommend you switch to Flynn (https://github.com/flynn/flynn ) instead,  which is under active development and enjoys a huge community base.

The issue you’re facing could be bug related, but with application disclaimer of no maintenance, it’s hard to tell, best to switch

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the desired [update strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy) of your Deployment by setting `.spec.strategy.type`. The default is `RollingUpdate`, but it seems you are looking for `Recreate`.

Comment: It's weird enough that every time we made a git push to deis the strategy is being reset.